# Using @Component as a @Directive: lint error

Tags: angular, static-analysis, lint

I want to use a `@Component` inside a table, but I think I can't use Angular
`<tags>` inside the elements `<tr>` of a table. I can't use a `@Directive` because I want to include html. What should I do?

I have the following in `my-page.html`:

```
<tr my-tag SOME_THINGS></tr>
```

Then, in `my-component.ts` I have

```
@Component({
  selector: '[my-tag]',
  templateUrl: './my-tag.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-tag.scss']
})
```

and in `my-component.html` I have:

```
<td>blah blah blah</td>
```

`@Component` is called inside a `tr` as a directive but it's not, because I want to include some html in it.

This raises the following `tslint` error:

The selector of the component "my-tag" should be used as element (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-05-03) (component-selector)

If I do the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-tag',
  templateUrl: './my-tag.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-tag.scss']
})
```

together with

```
<tr><app-my-tag></app-my-tag></tr>
```

I don't get lint errors, but it looks really weird to me, and I lose the style of the rows.

Which would be a possible solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Directives can manipulate the `DOM`. Use a directive.

Comment: Directives can manipulate the DOM, but can they add html? I think not. Sorry, but I don't fully understand your remark... :-(

Comment: Manipulating the DOM is actually more powerful than the ability to "add html" via a component - yoou can conditionally add, remove or change existing elements to the DOM parsed from an html document or snippet.

Comment: That sounds really interesting! Do you know any reference of how to parse the html document? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

just use `selector: 'tr[my-tag]'`. With such selectors you define your specific `tr`s

Comment: If I use this notation, I get the lint error `The selector of the component "my-component" should be named kebab-case and include dash (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-05-02)`. So, it seems it doesn't solve my problem...?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can append html elements from the directive. Here's how:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTestDir]'
})
export class TestDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2){}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const divText = this.renderer.createText('I am text inside div');
    this.renderer.appendChild(div, divText);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.elRef.nativeElement, div);
  }
}
```

In Your HTML

```
<td appTestDir>Blah Blah Blah</td>
```

This produces:
**Blah Blah Blah
I am text inside div**

Don't forget to add your Directive to the declarations array in *NgModule*.

Comment: But the text in `createText` is a whole 135 lines html file. Either there is the option to include its external content or the code will result pretty ugly...

Comment: You can style the newly created divs as you see fit.